# Bounding $\mathbb{E}(X_{i_1}\cdot \ldots \cdot X_{i_k}) $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Consider random variables $X_1,\ldots X_n$ with zero mean, variance at most $1$, $k$-wise independent $k\leq n $ and bounded: $|X_i|\leq C$ for some $C\geq 1$.

---

If I assume $k$ is **even**, how can I prove the following bound on the expectation of products of $k$ such random variables:  $$  \mathbb{E}(X_{i_1}\cdot \ldots \cdot X_{i_k}) \leq\ C^{2r},$$
where each term $X_{i_j}$  appears at least twice (so there can be at most $\frac{k}{2}$ distinct terms, since $k$ was even) and $\frac{k}{2}-r\leq \frac{k}{2}$ is the actual number of the distinct terms in the product.

(I'm pretty sure it is elementary to prove this and I'm overlooking some basic fact, since this is just a step in a proof that I can't follow.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each $X_i$ which appears in the product exactly twice accounts for $E(X_i^2)\leqslant1$. For every $X_i$ which appears in the product $n_i$ times with $n_i\geqslant3$, use the pointwise inequality $|X_i^{n_i}|\leqslant C^{n_i-2}X_i^2$ to deduce that $|E(X_i^{n_i})|\leqslant C^{n_i-2}$. Then the expectation in the question is at most $C^n$ where $n$ is the sum of these exponents $n_i-2$. Let $k=2\ell$, then there are $\ell-r$ exponents $n_i\geqslant3$ and $\sum\limits_in_i\leqslant2\ell$ hence $n=\sum\limits_i(n_i-2)\leqslant2\ell-2(\ell-r)=2r$, QED.

Comment: Thank you! The pointwise inequality was the missing key.